# App icon in notification bar not showing while app upgrade

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification

I schedule local notification for my application Version 1.1.
If i got local notification, at the time of app upgrade (downloading 1.2 version) , app icon in notification bar is not showing. Please see screenshot.

Is there any solution for it?

[image]

Comment: @BHASKAR What code? This seems to be bug in iOS.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 If you haven't already filed a bug report please do so.

Comment: @HAS sure i will do this..